# Need cell to return with hyperlink

Tags: excel, if-statement, hyperlink, vba

There is a drop down list, when a city is selected from the list, it needs to return a hyperlink so that we can just click on that to get info off the web. Each city will need to return a different website as well. example:

`if A1=B1, then returns site www.facebook.com`
`if A1=B2, then returns site www.google.com`
`if A1=B3, then returns site www.yahoo.com`

ect.ect.

I have tried the following IF statement but only errored out:

`=if(B4=AA7,=HYPERLINK(www.facebook.com,Facebook),"")`

Please help me as I am at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiny trick! ........use **two** cells.

In **C1** enter something like:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"http://www.facebook.com",IF(A1=B2,"http://www.google.com",""))
```

and in **D1** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK(C1,C1)
```

**D1** will be the "click-able" hyperlink.

**NOTE:**

If you have many different *URLs,* I would use a *VLOOKUP()* in **C1**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other things you can try.

You need to fix the formula.

> =if(B4=AA7,HYPERLINK("www.facebook.com","Facebook"),"")

You don't need to re-state the "=" for the Hyperlink formula and you need to use the " " to make the link and name as strings.